# excaping characters to run xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

I know that I need to escape the @cmd var to run:

```
declare @cmd 'xp_cmdshell ''echo Mary|Warrior > c:\test.txt'''
exec (@cmd)
```

because the character '|' would fail when running the command.

So, previous running I set:

```
set @cmd = replace(@cmd, '|', '^|')
```

As @cmd var could be any string (sent by users)... What other characters do I need to worry about ?

(I know a couple of them such as >, <)

Comment: Why are you executing a string value that you receive from your users? This is a potential sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` to escape the special character.

```
declare @cmd varchar(max) = N'echo Mary^|Warrior > C:\test1.txt'
exec master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

OR

```
declare @cmd1 varchar(max) = N'xp_cmdshell ''echo Mary^|Warrior > C:\test11.txt'''
exec (@cmd1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this query, As sean mentioned it is potential sql injection

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(500) = N'echo ''Mary|Warrior'' > c:\test.txt'
exec master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```